# Catch Exceptions when using Completable.blockingAwait()

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I recently started using RxJava 2 and am wondering if its possible to catch more specific Exceptions when calling [`Completable.blockingAwait()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#blockingAwait()).

This is what I am doing:

```java
try {

  Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(@NonNull CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        e.onError(new IOException());
    }
  }).blockingAwait();

} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  Throwable cause = e.getCause();

  if(cause instanceof IOException) {
      // Handle IOException
  }
}
```

And this is what I would like to do:

```java
try {

  Completable.create(new CompletableOnSubscribe() {
    @Override
    public void subscribe(@NonNull CompletableEmitter e) throws Exception {
        e.onError(new IOException());
    }
  }).blockingAwait();

} catch (IOException e) {
  // Handle IOException
}
```

Is there any possibility to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of lines down in the linked Javadoc there is the [`blockingGet`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#blockingGet()) operator that returns a `Throwable` which you can do `instanceof` checks with:

```
 Throwable err = Completable.error(new IOException()).blockingGet();
 if (err instanceof IOException) {
     // ...
 }
```

Comment: So in order to differentiate the returned/thrown Exceptions I have to use `instanceof`? Am I right, that there is no other option for [`Single.blockingGet()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#blockingGet()) as to catch the `RuntimeException` and use `instanceof` for error handling?

Comment: `blockingGet` doesn't throw and manually throwing the returned error looks a bit awkward.